# Forgot Username LWC controller throws error outside community

Tags: apex, lightning-community, global-methods

I'm trying to implement this [forgot username](https://www.infallibletechie.com/2018/04/simple-forgot-username-feature-in.html) component. And the Apex Controller code works when I test in the builder. But if I test it without logging in it errors out.

```
global with sharing class ForgotUsernameController {
@AuraEnabled
global static User fetchUser(String emailAddress) {
    List < User > listUsers = [ SELECT Id, Username, IsActive FROM User WHERE Email =: emailAddress ];
    if ( listUsers.size() > 0 ) {
        User usr = listUsers[0];
        return usr;
    } else {
        User noUser = new User();
        noUser.Username = 'No user found with that email';
        return noUser;
    }
}
```

In the controller... the response is ERROR outside of login, it's SUCCESS inside.

```
({
findUser : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.searchBool", true);
    var action = component.get("c.fetchUser");
    action.setParams({
        emailAddress : component.get("v.email")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        console.dir(response); // this response is ERROR
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {

            if(response.getReturnValue() == "null")
            {
                component.set("v.userRecord", "No user found!");
            } else {
                component.set("v.userRecord", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

})

Answer (score 0):

The apex class requires permissions from the Guest User Profile.
The Guest User Profile is under Community Builder -> Settings -> General -> Guest User Profile.